# Perform a loop with filter instead of map

Tags: reactjs

I have an array with alert in. They are going to be displayed different places dependent on the type:

```
{bankDetailsAlerts
  .filter(
    (alert) => alert.alertType === AlertType.BankDetails
  )
  .map((alert, index) => (
    <Alert
      key={index}
      color="info"
      toggle={() => onDismissBankDetailsAlert(alert)}
    >
      I am an alert and I can be dismissed! {alert.id}
    </Alert>
  ))}
```

I have only found a sample where both map and filter is used. Can't you use just filter or is the map neede? I tried removing the map both then I get an error. Can above in any way be written more elegant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a little difference between [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). **`Array#filter` will iterate through your array and then will only return the elements that meet your condition** which is in your case is `alert.alertType === AlertType.BankDetails` so whenever this gets true the corresponding element will be returned (will push into an array). But on the other hand, **`Array#map` will iterate through your array and will do something in each iteration and finally, it will return a shallow copy of your previously used array**. Which is in your case it will only create an `Alert` in each iteration like this:

```
<Alert
    key={index}
    color='info'
    toggle={() => onDismissBankDetailsAlert(alert)}
  >
    I am an alert and I can be dismissed! {alert.id}
</Alert>
```

**NOTE:** Your code is based on two steps, first filtering an array and get the desired elements from it and then iterate through the filtered array to create a component.

**So in your particular case since you have to return your final elements to your JSX you have to use `Array#map` since `Array#forEach` won’t return any element, it’s better to keep your code the way it was**.

Comment: Thanks. When I follow your sample no alerts are shown in the UI.

Comment: @ThomasSegato Oh, my bad I missed a little point heresince you need to return your final output to the JSX you have to use `Array#map` for sure.

Comment: What I was afraid of. Can you update your answer and I will approve it. Thanks alot.

Comment: Thanks your input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
var filteredAlert = bankDetailsAlerts
  .filter(
    (alert) => alert.alertType === AlertType.BankDetails
  );

  filteredAlert.foreach((alert, index) => (
    <Alert
      key={index}
      color="info"
      toggle={() => onDismissBankDetailsAlert(alert)}
    >
      I am an alert and I can be dismissed! {alert.id}
    </Alert>
  ))}
```